# Color cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, colors, processing

I am trying to make a simple maze game currently using processing in Eclipse. I am trying to make it so every time the mouse touches the walls, it resets, and the only way I know how to do this is by using the get() function.

However, when I try to get() the color, it has no idea what color is. I have tried many times to find a solution but still cannot. If you can help me by explaining it in simple terms since I am a bit younger than most on this website that would be helpful. Here is my pasted code.

```
package MegaPackage;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PImage;
//Main method. Insert public variables and entities here.
public class FlatShooter extends PApplet{
public void settings(){
size(900,900);  
}
public static void main(String [] args){
    String[] processingArgs = {"FlatShooter"};
    FlatShooter flatShooter = new FlatShooter();
    PApplet.runSketch(processingArgs, flatShooter);
}
PImage background;
PImage life1Image;
PImage life2Image;
PImage life3Image;
PImage redEnemyImage;
public float xSpeedPlayer = 9;
public int score;
public int enemies;
public int lives;
public boolean moving = false;
public boolean moving2 = false;
public void setup(){        
    background=loadImage("maze.png");
    life1Image=loadImage("life_heart.png");
    life2Image=loadImage("life_heart.png");
    life3Image=loadImage("life_heart.png");
}
//Draw stuff
public void draw(){
    background(background);

}
public class Cursor{
    public void CheckPosX(){
        color color_beside_mouse = get(mouseX, mouseY);
    }

}
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the `color` datatype in the Processing editor. Like I said in your previous question, you should probably stick with that before you try to do more advanced stuff in Eclipse.

In Eclipse, you have to use the underlying representation, where colors are actually `int` values.

You should also get into the habit of looking this stuff up in [the Processing JavaDoc](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/). Find the `get()` function in the `PApplet` class and notice that it has an `int` return type.

One last thing: while you can use colors to detect collision, you'll be much better off if you use [collision detection](http://HappyCoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection).

Comment: Thanks! This really helped, however I don't quite understand why I have so many downvotes on my question? Was it not a good question?

Comment: @ZubinBhaumik It's a reasonable question, but it's buried under a lot of extra code. You should try to isolate your problem to a [mcve] instead of posting your whole project. Get rid of most of your variables and import statements, since they aren't directly related to your problem. See also [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Also note that tagging your Processing question with the [tag:java] tag can attract downvotes from Java developers who aren't familiar with Processing. See also: [Processing != Java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353845/stack-overflow-mentorship-research-project).